# Minify JSON and copy the result to file using Webpack?

Tags: json, webpack, compression

I have a couple of language files that I just copy to a location on disk, and I need to continue to do so for now.

The problem is that they're not minified and I would like to do so using WebPack 3.X as this is what we use... :)

Something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-jsonmin but without the grunt part.

What I have:
Uncompressed JSON in src/lang/*.json

What I want:
Compressed JSON in dist/lang/*.json

/J

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of old, but if anyone is still pondering, here's how I did it:

```
// npm i -D node-json-minify copy-webpack-plugin

//webpack.config.js
const JSONMinifyPlugin = require('node-json-minify'),
      CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

options.plugins = [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
            /* i18n */
            from: path.join(__dirname, 'src', '_locales'),
            transform: function(content) {
                // minify json
                return JSONMinifyPlugin(content.toString());
            },
            to: path.join(__dirname, 'build', '_locales')
        }
    ])
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In webpack 5 you can use [JsonMinimizerWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/json-minimizer-webpack-plugin/).

It works for both rules and CopyPlugin.

```
const JsonMinimizerPlugin = require("json-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          context: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
          from: "./src/*.json",
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      // For webpack@5 you can use the `...` syntax to extend existing minimizers (i.e. `terser-webpack-plugin`), uncomment the next line
      // `...`
      new JsonMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
  },
};
```